# Is there a quick way to update Material-UI in React components for deprecated properties

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are upgrading our application from React 0.13 to React 16.0 so there are so many changes and so much that we have to update and replace because of how much has been deprecated and no backwards compatibility.

For instance, we are using material-ui and we have over 70 Dialog usages in 60+ components that I have to change all the actions from JSON text to child components now, and it will take a good day or so to do that. And this is just one deprecation. It took me all weekend to fix the menuItems in DropDownMenu.

Is there a codemod or something out there that can make this process less painful?

Comment: Are you doing the upgrades incrementally? When I install newer version of MUI, I install them one at a time to watch out for breaking changes. Which version of MUI are you using?

Comment: Thanks Mike for the response. We were at 0.13.1 and there are 48 versions to get to 0.19.4. I think going one version at a time would be incredibly slower for us than jumping directly to 0.19.4 and what about all the other plugins we use, they have to all line up, so upgrading React one version at time where we were about that many versions behind too. All our versions were about 3 years behind. I think we got almost everything in 1 month of work. React, Material-UI, Router, etc.